# Find the shortest path between two nodes in a graph in (Prolog) and display the result as array

Tags: path, prolog, member, shortest-path

[[image]]

How can I write (using `print_path`) a rule to print the path from one node to another if exists

```
Print_path(a, c, Res) --->  Res=[a, f, c]
```

What I did was :

```
path(a,b). %there is a path from a to b 
path(a,f).
path(b,c).
path(c,d).
path(c,e).
path(e,d).
path(f,g).
path(f,c).
path(f,e).`
```

I do not know what to do next.

Comment: "I don't know what to do next" doesn't give us much to go on, in terms of how much you understand. Are you comfortable with writing basic relations in prolog? If so, have a read about recursion and the accumulator pattern (both in general, and specifically with respect to prolog). In general you will want to define a helper predicate that recursively fills in an accumulator with the required nodes, and uses the base case to copy the final contents of the accumulator onto an output variable. Look at a basic prolog textbook, the "train stations" problem is literally the first problem in any book

Comment: "Won't somebody please do my homework for me?"

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thank you i am studying (recursion) right now , and I almost  understand how the solution